# Why does my NAS disk with 100Mbps NIC transfer at 30-40 MB/s?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, raid, nas, speed

I have a "Western Digital My Book World Edition II (white light)" bought in 2009 with two WD Green 1TB drives in RAID0 in my home network.
I recently turned it on after "several years of offlineness" (excuse my english) and transferred 10+ gigabytes to my Windows 10 PC.

To my surprise it transferred with a constant speed of 30-40 MB/s.

I copied some data back and it wrote with a expected speed of 10-15 MB/s.

My question is, how is that possible with it's 100Mbps NIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Western Digital My Book World Edition II with model #'s WD60000H2NC, WD40000H2NC, &
WD20000H2NC all come with a 1000Mbit lan controller.

https://support.wdc.com/product.aspx?ID=118&&

I suspect you are mis-reading the transfer output from windows. More then likely you just saw a 40 Mbps transfer, not 40 MB/s.

Comment: Your link refers to the "blue rings" version (https://support.wdc.com/product.aspx?ID=106), not the "white light" (https://support.wdc.com/product.aspx?ID=117&lang=en)

Comment: What's the model number? That link looks like the first edition. Scroll down to the bottom. Two of the "white light" models shipped with gigabit nics.

Comment: The sticker on the underside says: "MDL: WD20000H2NC-00"

Comment: I updated your answer and the link, try taking a 100 MB file and timing the transfer. The guesstimate from windows isn't always accurate.

Comment: @bone so it does indeed have that 1 GB port

Comment: Image of the sticker: https://imgur.com/a/Shceg

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Ok, I'll accept that. That's news to me after these 8 years and 800GB data. Can you tell me why the write speed is like a 100Mbps NIC? Slow controller?

Comment: Sure, it depends on the motherboard of the controller, there is almost always a bottle neck in-between the storage media, motherboard, and lan controller. You can try plugging into the USB on some models for better performance (but defeats the purpose of having a nas). But it's basically limited by the processor, ram, & bus backplane of the device itself.